# How to add hyperlink in word using NPOI

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, npoi, xwpf

I have been researching for the best thirdparty dll to generate word document. Finally **I found NPOI is very good to write word document.**

But I am unable to **add the hyperlink** to document.

Comment: You will have very less documentation availability for NPOI. Whay can't use the Open XML - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument.aspx

Comment: Thank you @MaheshB, first I had decided to use Open XML because it is one of the Microsoft product. But after compare it against NPOI I feel NPOI has been updating its dll and fixing their bugs with the updated features.

Please check this out and help me understand: https://dotnet.libhunt.com/compare-npoi-vs-open-xml-sdk

Answer (score 0):

The new NPOI examples is added at https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi-examples/tree/main/xwpf/CreateHyperlink

```
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.CreateParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.CreateRun();
        run.SetText("This is a text paragraph having ");

        XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkrun = CreateHyperlinkRun(paragraph, "https://www.google.com");
        hyperlinkrun.SetText("a link to Google");
        hyperlinkrun.SetColor("0000FF");
        hyperlinkrun.SetUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.Single);
```